# AWS.CloudWatch constructor set batch_size and batch_limit

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a node/express application that logs to cloudwatch.

I want to be able to set the cloudwatch logs batch_limit and batch_size parameters in the
AWS.CloudWatch() constructor.

```
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? That generally does not make sense because a cloudwatch client can do a lot more things than those that respect those batch limits. It therefore would be quite weird to expose that settings through a constructor. Instead you can create your own MyCloudWatchClient that calls the original client with the added parameters when a method is invoked that should respect these settings.

Comment: I want to configure this because the logs sometimes exceed the 1 megabyte batch size limit and throws an error. I want a way to configure it so that it does exceed the limit per batch.

Comment: @luk2302 can you demonstrate how this can be done? because I'm quite new to AWS.